# duplicate records in table in SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

i have a  form which is supervisor ,manager and director aspx forms . when any user upload documents then this document first goes to supervsior then manager and then director for approve/reject

user "kat" uplaod document and his/her document goes for approval /reject to  supervsior,manager,director and it seems like this in table

```
Seqno DocID ApproveID ApproveBy DesigID ApproveDate

1        16        1              abc            1           10/11/2013

2        16        1               def           2           11/12/2013

3       16          1            xyzz         3             14/12/2013
```

when user  "kat" see document wheather document approve/reject it seems like this

```
docname fileuploaded uploadedate deptype status

finad   fina.docx   04/11/2013  finance approve
```

when another user upload document and when this document goes for approval to supervsior,manager,director

then in supervsior form it seems like this

```
docid    docname     filename department      email             uploadedby uploadedate

  16     finad      fina.docx    fiance   sadas@gmail.com        kat        04/11/2013 (this is old document)

   17    hrrr         hrr.docs  finance    abc@gmail.com         john   15/11/2013  (this is new document)
```

so when supervsior approv document (docid 17) then old document which is already approve/reject also save in database and after this in table seems like this

```
Seqno DocID     ApproveID         ApproveBy   DesigID    ApproveDate

1        16        1              abc            1           10/11/2013

2        16        1               def           2           11/12/2013

3       16          1              xyzz          3             14/12/2013
4       16          1              ssd           1             15/11 2013
5       17          3              dfsdf         1             15/11/2013
```

here 1 is approve and 3 is pending

"i use dropdown and in dropdown i fill all values in dropdown "approve,reject ,pending"

[drodown](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=rm5wz7&s=8)
so when "kat" agian  to see his /her document it sees me like this

```
docname fileuploaded uploadedate deptype status

finad   fina.docx   04/11/2013  finance reject
```

i use sp like this

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[approveddd]
@DocID int,
@ApproveID int,     
@ApproveBy nvarchar(50),
@DesigID int
as

IF EXISTS(Select DocID from Approval where DocID=@DocID and AppoveBy=@ApproveBy)
Update Approval set ApproveID=@ApproveID where DocID=@DocID and AppoveBy=@ApproveBy
ELSE
insert Approval (DocID,ApproveID,AppoveBy,DesigID,ApproveDate)
values(@DocID,@ApproveID,@ApproveBy,@DesigID,GETDATE())
```

Comment: And your question is...? I can't work out what the question is, I'm afraid.

Comment: is there any solution to stop save records in table which is already exists in table.. like in above once supervsior approve/reject 16 document then when any supervsior approve/reject documents then 16 document record not save in table beacuse this is aleardy approve/reject

Comment: It looks to me like it's already doing that. I see "IF EXISTS(..) UPDATE ... ELSE INSERT..."

Comment: but based on what you put above, there is no duplicate data since the document is not repeated with the ApprovedBy

Comment: you should update only the Pending documents so add this criteria to your update statement

Comment: So in Table 4, do you want to store Seqno 1 and 5 only?

Comment: there is not one supervsior,manager,director user there is so many users and when director approve documents i want to shows users only these documents when direcor approve/rejec

Comment: I understand your general concept but I don't understand what your actual problem is, I'm afraid. Your title says "duplicate records in table in SQL", which duplicates are you trying to eliminate?

Comment: when two different records are exist in records and 1st record is always approve/reject then when supervsior login and  to approve/reject 2nd documents then with this 2nd documents 1st documents also save in table and i dont want this when 1st reocrd alrady exist then why again same record is goes..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about your dataset but how about using the 
unique sequence number (`seqno`) instead of 
the `DocID` and `ApproveBy`? That has saved me a few times. It may work better because the 
`seqno` is unique. I guess you have to think of how to handle
the case where one `DocID` and `ApproveBy` generates >1 seqno.

So instead of

```
IF EXISTS(Select DocID from Approval where DocID=@DocID and AppoveBy=@ApproveBy)
    Update Approval set ApproveID=@ApproveID where DocID=@DocID and AppoveBy=@ApproveBy
ELSE
    insert Approval (DocID,ApproveID,AppoveBy,DesigID,ApproveDate)
    values(@DocID,@ApproveID,@ApproveBy,@DesigID,GETDATE())
;
```

try

```
-- Get the sequence number  
DECLARE @seqno int;
SET @Seqno = (SELECT seqno 
              FROM Approval a
              where a.[ DocID ]=@DocID and 
              a.[ApproveBy ]==@ApproveBy);


-- Update record if exist, otherwise insert
IF (@seqno is not null or @seqno = '') 
BEGIN 
    Update Approval set ApproveID=@ApproveID where seqno=@seqno
end 
else 
    begin 
    insert Approval (DocID,ApproveID,AppoveBy,DesigID,ApproveDate)
    values(@DocID,@ApproveID,@ApproveBy,@DesigID,GETDATE())
end ;
```

Comment: ok i try this when i upload new document and supervsior approve/reject this new document then record not goes to database check this pic http://i60.tinypic.com/1z6770l.png

Comment: Are you sure the issue with with the sql and not with e.g. the asp code? Does the insert/update query give you any error messages? Is the procedure selecting the correct `seqno` etc?

Comment: SeqNo is autogenerated in sql ..so how it is inserted and add in code

Comment: Exactly. so you would match on the `seqno` rather than the `DocID` and `ApproveBy` as `seqno` is unique. Looking at it a bit closer, you have horrible spelling mistakes in your code. Look at this: `Select DocID from Approval where DocID=@DocID and AppoveBy=@ApproveBy` . There is no column called `AppoveBy` without an "r". I thought the column was called that but it doesn't make any sense

Comment: yeah appoveby is a column and i correct it by approveby

Comment: That's why your code fails then. You are trying to insert a value into a column that doesn't exist.

Comment: Well, the example table you posted does not have a field called `AppoveBy` and the query would fail because of that. I can only go by what you post.